# I want to add a title in the middle of the frame

Tags: beamer

I want to add a title in the middle of the frame just like this image .
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either add such a block manually

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]{section title}
      \usebeamerfont{section title}Introduction\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \endgroup
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Or you could tell beamer to automatically add section pages:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
    \sectionpage
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your time ! it works

Comment: @TexNewLearner You're welcome!